# Restore mirrored database as non-mirrored

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mirroring

We have a Sql Server 2012 mirrored database that we want to restore (essentially, copy) to a different server and run in a non-mirrored mode.  The other server is simply for application testing and does not require mirroring.  What are the proper restore steps?  I imagine that at some point I'll need to ALTER DATABASE SET PARTNER OFF but when?  Is it safe to do a full restore and then set partner off?  I certainly wouldn't want my restored db to begin participating in mirroring .

Answer (score 0):

I found that after a restore, the SET PARTNER OFF command said that it was already off.  So I guess restore turns off mirroring.  That leaves a different question of how to restore a mirrored db as a mirrored db but that doesn't concern me right now.